Why do I receive a deprecated dependency warning while installing expo
I am very new with nodejs and I would like to learn about how to use React Native with expo to build a Samrtphone App.
Note, I have an old Macbook with 13.7 Ventura and I can not upgrate to the latest MacOS because my Macbook do not have a M4 ship (Intel). As I have an old MacOS; I wunder if it would be the cause of my depreciate warning, as I am using the lastest version of the framework.
Let see what I did because writing my issue. My be my mistake starts from on of this point

I installed nvm with npm curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.40.0/install.sh | bash
I installed node nvm install 22

Now I wanted to install expo but before I enter npx expoand I reveive a quetsion

Need to install the following packages: expo@52.0.11 Ok to proceed?
(y) y

I typed y and I received serveral warning

npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and
leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good
and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is
much more comprehensive and powerful. npm warn deprecated
@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This
proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this
plugin is no longer maintained. Please use
@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead. npm warn
deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This
proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this
plugin is no longer maintained. Please use
@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead. npm warn deprecated
@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has
been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no
longer maintained. Please use
@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead. npm warn deprecated
rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported npm
warn deprecated @xmldom/xmldom@0.7.13: this version is no longer
supported, please update to at least 0.8.* npm warn deprecated
glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn
deprecated rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer
supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9
are no longer supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions
prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3:
Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn deprecated
glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

Should I suppose, I am going to have future problem? Should I consider that the process failed?
then, I decided to try to create an expo project
npx create-expo-app@latest
Need to install the following packages:
create-expo-app@3.1.1
Ok to proceed? (y) y

It success but I receive again the warning

npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and
leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good
and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is
much more comprehensive and powerful. npm warn deprecated
@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This
proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this
plugin is no longer maintained. Please use
@babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead. npm warn
deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This
proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this
plugin is no longer maintained. Please use
@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead. npm warn deprecated
rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported npm
warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This
proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this
plugin is no longer maintained. Please use
@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead. npm warn deprecated
rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported npm
warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer
supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9
are no longer supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions
prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3:
Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn deprecated
glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn
deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer
supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9
are no longer supported npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions
prior to v9 are no longer supported npm warn deprecated
@xmldom/xmldom@0.7.13: this version is no longer supported, please
update to at least 0.8.* npm warn deprecated domexception@4.0.0: Use
your platform's native DOMException instead npm warn deprecated
abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods
instead

Later I discover, that I should run npm install --global expo-cli and I guess I should have tried first...
My questions are?

Because I have an old MacOS, can it be a reason of the warning?
How would have be the right sequence to install expo?
After I installed nodejs, should i have just run the command npm install --global expo-cli?
How can I remove all of my expo installation and start from the begining with expo-cli only?

Thanks a lot for your clarification

These deprecation warnings apply to nested dependencies of the package, they aren't specific to the system and can be ignored.
expo-cli is deprecated and shouldn't be used. If you installed it globally, uninstall it with npm rm -g expo-cli to avoid confusion. The up-to-date package is @expo/cli but this is the actual problem with globally installed packages, they eventually become out of date. npx expo@latest (which wraps @expo/cli) would be generally preferred, unless performance is a big concern.npx may provide overhead because it currently doesn't fully support caching for global packages. This is mentioned only for the sake of completeness, because global Expo CLI shouldn't generally be used.
Expo CLI package isn't a replacement for create-expo-app. The latter initializes a project with the preferable setup, which contains local expo dependency the project is designed to work with. npx expo uses local dependency when it's available without overhead. This is what the documentation suggests.
